# using arduino tone function on two pin at the same time

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to make an smart car with Arduino Mega, and I need to turn both of the back wheels on for an specific time sometimes. I've been told that I can set a "digital HIGH" time using tone, But as I need them to work in a same time, Is there a way to set tone for two pins in one line or something to do instead?

Thanks for your help.

```
#include <Servo.h>
/////////////////////
Servo servo;
/////////////////////
int trig = 12;
int echo = 13;
long duration;
int  distance;
int dist_right;
int dist_left;
int ang = 90;
unsigned int value = 255;
unsigned long tone_time = 3000;
float forward_time;
/////////////////////
int ena = 35;
int in1 = 7;
int in2 = 6;
int in3 = 5;
int in4 = 4;
int enb = 47;
/////////////////////
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo.attach(22);
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ena, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enb, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(ena, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(enb, HIGH);

}
void loop() {
    servo.write(90);
    distance = dist();
    if(distance<=15)
    {
       for(ang;ang>=0;ang-=2)
       {
        servo.write(ang);
        delay(30);
       }
       dist_right = dist();
       Serial.println(dist_right);
       for(ang;ang<=180;ang+=2)
       {
        servo.write(ang);
        delay(30);
       }
       dist_left = dist();
       Serial.println(dist_left);
       for(ang;ang>=90;ang-=2)
       {
        servo.write(ang);
        delay(30);
       }
       if(dist_right>=dist_left)
       {
        tone(in3, value, tone_time);
       }
       else if(dist_right<dist_left)
       {
        tone(in1, value, tone_time);
       }
       servo.write(90);
       ang=90;
    }
    else{
      forward_time=distance/25;
      tone((in1,in3), value, forward_time);
    }
}
int dist(){ 
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH); 
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH); 
  distance= duration*0.034/2;
  return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.99% sure, that your motors will not feel the time differencce if you turn them one by one. Try simplest case and you will see.

```
// Define your wheel control pins (use same as in your mega)
const int motor1Pin = 5;
const int motor1Pin = 6;

// somewhere in setup method
outputMode(motor1Pin, OUTPUT);
outputMode(motor2Pin, OUTPUT);

// Create function to turn motors and remember the time
unsigned long turnMotorsOn(int seconds) {
    // turn motors ant return time when they should be stopped
    return millis() + seconds * 1000;
}

// In you code check if it is time to turn off
if (millis() > timeWhenTurnMotorsOff) {
    // turn them off
}
```

Comment: okay, but how to keep them on for an specific time? delay is unusable here

Comment: Use millis() to determine time you turn them on. And then, in loop() keep checking if it is time to turn them off.

Comment: you're right, but still, no way to double use tone? it's a bit easier than millies cause you can set time and pwm output in one line

Comment: I think you could. But I'm not sure about frequency parameter in tone(). Anyway, timing is better, because you could stop your motors on any other conditions, i.e. by signal from distance sensor.

Comment: yes i'm using that, actually at the beginning of the loop I measure the distance. added the code above.

Comment: You can't use tone(), it is blocking function. See [Arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/).
*Only one tone can be generated at a time. If a tone is already playing on a different pin, the call to tone() will have no effect.*

Comment: thanks for help bro. I did it with a combination of millies and delay. video in https://www.instagram.com/p/CHvtQeHsjZ2/.